# Showing Fresh data In GridView

Tags: c#-3.0

I am having a grid view which shows data depending on a criteria, now once I delete the row from the grid I want that again the fresh result should be presented in the grid, depending upon that same condition which was supplied earlier

Answer (score 0):

After deleteing the row (I'm assuming that you delete using postback to server) do

```
Server.Transfer("/app/mypage.asp")
```

to same page. This will return page with up to date data